# Installer crashed

Tags: dual-boot

I have acer laptop with windows 8.1. I tried installing ubuntu 14.04 from bootable usb drive alongside windows. I changed bios settings from UEFI to LEGACY and secure boot from ENABLED to DISABLED. I chose option "INSTALL ALONGSIDE OTHER OPREATING SYSTEM" I got error message "Installer crashed" after the partition screen. What do I need to do to install ubuntu successfully? thanks,

Comment: Please do not re-ask questions. Why do you set to LEGACY?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: I changed from UEFI to LEGACY because my laptop was booting directly in windows even if I had Ubuntu bootable usb drive plugged in.

Comment: Did you choose boot options, or just stick in the flash drive and expect it to boot from it? You would have to go into boot options to select the USB, or BIOS to set it to boot from USB.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that you will need to do here.

1. Set your boot back to UEFI, or normal
2. Download Rufus - to create a bootable USB device
3. Boot to your USB by clicking F8 at startup to access boot options - or F1 to enter BIOS setup to set USB as first boot
4. Now continue with the installer as normal

There are so many issues with running your boot in Legacy. I tried it on my laptop just to see what would happen and I could never get Ubuntu to install.

I always recommend setting up partitions manually (if you know how) as well, and install from that route. This way you can choose the file extensions for each partition and designate the amount of disk space to each partition.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got fed up with waiting for all this to and fro communication. Too many issues with installation of Ubuntu and support is not timely or professional. I got my laptop formatted. Got rid of Ubuntu.